# Como chamar fragments no DrawerNavigation?

Tags: android

Criei um novo projeto no android studio e escolhi usar o `navigationDrawer`, criei minhas telas agora gostaria de chamá-las. Como faço pra implementar este método e alternar janelas no *menu* de uma aplicação usando o:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Fragment fragment = null;
    if (id == R.id.servic) {
       fragment = new Cronograma();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_camera)  {
        fragment = new Localizacao();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        fragment = new Sobre_aplicativo();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
        finish();
    }

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

ACTIVITY MAIN

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

CONTENT MAIN:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainFrame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

APP BAR MAIN:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

ACTIVITY MAIN DRAWER

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/servic"
        android:icon="@drawable/servico"
        android:title="Serviços" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/pref"
        android:title="A prefeitura" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/local"
        android:title="Localização" />

</group>

<item android:title="Informações">
    <menu>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/dev"
            android:title="Sobre o aplicativo" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
            android:icon="@drawable/exit"
            android:title="Sair" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O ideal é que o layout de sua activity tenha como um de seus elementos algo que sirva como "container", é muito comum usar um FrameLayout para esses casos.

Sendo assim, crie um método da activity que faça o seguinte:

```
String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(container (id do container), fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(backStateName);
        transaction.commit();
```

Esse método deve receber como parâmetro uma instância do fragmento que você quer abrir, Ex:

```
  if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
       abreFragmento(new CameraFragment());
  }
```

Assim, o fragmentManager da sua Activity vai substituir o que está no container pelo fragment que você instanciou.

Extra:

Nesse método mostrado, o fragmentManager guarda os fragments que foram abertos em ordem, se você usar abreFragment(new OutroFragment()) sendo que outro fragment já está aberto, o mesmo entra em onStop() e você pode voltar para ele utilizando o método `fragmentManager.popBackStack()`.

Comment: Joao estava fazendo assim:  `int id = item.getItemId();
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
           fragment = new Cronograma();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery)  {
            fragment = new Localizacao();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
            fragment = new Sobre_aplicativo();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
            finish();
        }`
So que a tela ta aparecendo por cima do menu.

Comment: Manda como ta o seu xml desse layout.